# Long delay getting data from a server for one site but not 2 others

Tags: performance, drupal

We're running 3 different Drupal (Pressflow to be specific) sites on the same server. The 2nd and 3rd sites were cloned from the first one and load just fine. The first one, though, is taking a few seconds to connect and start sending data back from the server. Same box, same config (as far as we know), same modules, and generally the same theme. Here's what Pingdom shows...

**Fast site:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZilC.png

**Slow site:** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Um1M.png

Edit: Those are from Pingdom, the yellow indicating "The web browser is waiting for data from the server"

The configs are the same, performance options same, server configs, as far as we can tell are the same. The delay occurs before any page elements are visible so it's not an on-page object problem or a page speed problem.

Could this be a config issue with the server? Where should we be investigating?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's any help, the long yellow bar on the slow Pingdom chart represents: "The web browser is waiting for data from the server"

Comment: Just so this doesn't go unanswered... reinstalled Drupal and problem was fixed so likely idiotic code added by the previous host.

Answer (score 0):

I would try increasing the size of your MySQL cache.  It's possible the fast sites have their particular queries cached and the slow site has a query that doesn't quite fit the cache, so the MySQL query results need to be regenerated each time.

Just a guess!

Comment: The sites are clones of each other with comparable amounts of content. Even with no caching, they run fairly fast, it's just that connection time. Thanks for the response though... if the host was more responsive we'd have them check!